# Smudge error: Error downloading

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm not sure if this is the right forum to discuss git-lfs but as we have a tag for it I'll post my question. I have read the ["Troubleshoot Git LFS in Bitbucket" page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-git-lfs-in-bitbucket-831652519.html).

I'm getting the following error when runing:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /home/dan/.ssh/keyname;  git clone git@bitbucket.org:[repo name removed].git'
```

> $ git-lfs smudge -- [Filename removed].zip Error downloading object:
>   [Filename removed].zip ([code removed]): Smudge error: Error downloading
>   [Filename removed].zip ([code removed]): [[code removed] Object does
>   not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
>
> [404] Object does not exist on the server
>   github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
>           /tmp/docker_run/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170:
>   [[code removed]] Object does not exist on the server
>   github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
>           /tmp/docker_run/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170:
>   Error downloading [Filename removed].zip ([code removed])
>   github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors.newWrappedError
>           /tmp/docker_run/src/github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/errors/types.go:170:
>   Smudge error

Has anyone got any advice?

Answer (score 63):

I eventually found an answer by strich: on https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/911

> I've had similar issues in the past and I think there may be a
> potential bug in cloning with git lfs (Still to be determined). You
> can try this method of fetching the repo, which is in fact faster too:

```
// Skip smudge - We'll download binary files later in a faster batch
git lfs install --skip-smudge

// Do git clone here
git clone ...

// Fetch all the binary files in the new clone 
git lfs pull

// Reinstate smudge
git lfs install --force
```

> This only needs to be done once to initialize the clone for the first
> time.
>
> Please do test it and let me know if it fixes it.

Comment: I can't say I fixed this. Eventually I gave up as I got other errors.

Comment: If you don't want to give up and re-download the whole repository, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989902/git-pull-smudge-filter-lfs-failed (especially the answer about `lfs.url` configuration option).

Comment: direct link to the github answer https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/911#issuecomment-169998792

Comment: If you have submodules: `git submodule foreach git lfs pull`

Comment: Tried this method. It got some file, but still failed to get some files, the repository may not be in a consistent state. It could be dangerous.

Answer (score 29):

This corruption can happen due to another developer's misconfigured git-lfs that pushed to the repository, or sometimes due to some unusual failure during a push. Try re-sending the missing object (using its object ID) from a working tree:

```
git lfs push --object-id <remote> <oid>
```

The OID should be in the Smudge error message.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this, but this worked for me. Maybe in the original lfs push the file didn't send through properly (used sourcetree originally). Thanks
P.S. idk why people downvoted this, it actually helped me

Comment: I tried the command. However, a new clone still fails. Maybe it's a problem of our Gitlab.

Comment: It turns out that our Gitlab has a wrong lfs setting. The lfs data are not synced between machines as expected.

Comment: @ElpieKay can you please expand more on the fix for you? I encountered the same issue, the command above works, but I feel it is more of a workaround. It should work without having to manually push the object id.

Comment: @GeorgeCimpoies We have two machines that hold repository data. One for push and fetch, and the other for fetch only. By the previous settings, the lfs data on the push-and-fetch machine was not synced to the other. When a user happened to fetch from the other machine, the data was just unavailable.

Comment: This worked for one object, but on my project there ended up being hundreds of objects that needed pushing. For that, `git lfs push --all` uploaded all objects.

Comment: This dis not solve my problem.