Git checkout via groovy script executed by Jenkins cannot find repository
I have a jenkins server which executes a build job at my workplace. The flow is as follows:

I have a repository with groovy scripts where a specific script written for a specific project is found. I will call this RepoOne.
Then, I have a repository which the actual project files are found, and which are needed by the build. I will call this repo RepoTwo.

In RepoOne, I have the git checkout call in the groovy script:
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/${branch}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: ${myCredentials}, url: "${gitRepo}"]]])

And Jenkins is able to clone RepoOne without problems, using an SSH Key configured for that specific GitHub Server (btw, RepoOne and RepoTwo are on 2 different GitHub Servers, both have my user configured for SSH connection)
But it cannot clone RepoTwo, and gives me the following error:
ERROR: Checkout failed
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f 801a93051dedf64ed14e6d05b1c3ebbfffcdfa52" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Downloading Delivery/Out/MyFile.exe (127 MB)
Error downloading object: Delivery/Out/MyFile.exe (3046bf3): Smudge error: Error downloading Delivery/Out/MyFile.exe (3046bf32dba11efe5f9ff3a1f8cf43ad0db16933c35fb8502037bac306324ad9): batch request: Repository not found.: exit status 1

Errors logged to 'D:\js\ws\MyProject\Build\.git\lfs\logs\20241113T145249.8471427.log'.
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: Delivery/Out/MyFile.exe smudge filter lfs failed

    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2846)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3174)
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Build_PC
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1826)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1042)
        at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:138)
        at PluginClassLoader for git-client/jdk.proxy91/jdk.proxy91.$Proxy209.execute(Unknown Source)
        at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM._checkout(GitSCM.java:1360)
        at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1277)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
        at PluginClassLoader for workflow-step-api//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at PluginClassLoader for opentelemetry-api//io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$1(Context.java:212)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 801a93051dedf64ed14e6d05b1c3ebbfffcdfa52
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:3202)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:170)
    at PluginClassLoader for git-client//org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at PluginClassLoader for git//hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1279)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:136)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:101)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-scm-step//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:88)
    at PluginClassLoader for workflow-step-api//org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at PluginClassLoader for opentelemetry-api//io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$1(Context.java:212)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
ERROR: Failed to checkout : hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout 801a93051dedf64ed14e6d05b1c3ebbfffcdfa52
Finished: FAILURE

What other solutions could there be?
I have tried:
SSH Key is configured properly for my user, for both GitHub servers (I have tested this with "ssh -vT ")
Manual cloning of RepoTwo is, however, possible, just not via the groovy script.
Switching between multiple credentials which have full permissions also return the same error.

Are you using the same pipeline checkout step for RepoTwo that you're using for RepoOne, or a custom shell command?

yes, the same checkout command

check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521122/smudge-error-error-downloading

UPDATE: issue was solved using an internal library
