# git pull fails when pulling lfs file

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I'm getting an Authorization error and a 'smudge filter' error when I git pull from my publicly-visible repo. The error occurs when downloading a file that is pointed to by git lfs. My repo looks like this:

```
folder
folder
.gitattributes
python file
big_binary_file.h5
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
Downloading big_binary_file.h5 (262 MB)
Error downloading object: big_binary_file.h5: Smudge error: Error downloading big_binary_file.h5:
batch response: Authorization error: https://github.com/user/repo.git/objects/batch
Check that you have proper access to the repository

Errors logged to log_path/log.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: big_binary_file.h5: smudge filter lfs failed
```

I don't believe I have any authorization issues because the other files from my repo pull seamlessly. My repo is public and a git lfs file shouldn't have any special authorization needed, right?

My .gitattrbutes correctly identifies that '.h5' files should be fetched using LFS. It looks like this:

```
*.h5 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Has anyone gotten a similar error when they git pull and can they shine light on where I went wrong or what might be the cause of this?

Here are things I've tried (and you might try to if you run into this page looking for advice:)

- I've tried following the advice in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989902/git-pull-smudge-filter-lfs-failed)

My `lfs.url` is the same as `remote.origin.url`

- I've looked at my `git credentials` to make sure they are set correctly.
- I've verified that my repo is publicly visible and that my `.gitattributes` is setup correctly.
- I've made sure `git lfs` is setup on my system and have used it to push to the same repo.
- I've tried diagnosing `git lfs logs last`.
- I tried using `git reset` and then pulling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `lfs.url` should not be the same as your `remote.origin.url`.  If you don't need a different LFS remote than your regular Git remote, you should omit the `lfs.url` configuration setting and let Git LFS autodiscover it.

Otherwise, typically your `lfs.url` is supposed to end with `/info/lfs`.  Thus, `https://github.com/user/repo.git/info/lfs` would be the right option.